# Extract a significant sample of data from a non-normal distribution before modelling a fitting curve

Tags: distributions, standard-deviation, curve-fitting

Background: In my master thesis I am measuring how many areas(in square meter) are suitable for greening at different building height in an urban area. So I have two variable: Suitable Areas and Height. In the following plot is it shown how the amount of Suitable Area changes at different heights and I plot a curve that join those points (an automatic function of ggplot2 in R) [image: Suitable area on height]

Now my supervisor required to model a fitting curve (***and to find its formula***) that describes the data(the distribution of suitables area at different height), but before doing so he suggest me to consider reducing my data. Therefore the question is at which height the 95 % of the total Suitable area are located and consequentially remove the rest from my distribution. I guess this would mean to cut the tail on the left of my plot.

I thought that this 95% of the measurement comes from the "68-95-99.7" rule (three-sigma rule) based on standard deviation. But the three-sigma rule works better for normal distribution, while **my distribution is non-normal**, and I fear that it would neglect values in the first meters, considering them as outliers.

1. Is a good practice at all to select a significant sample of my
   distribution before modelling a fitting curve?
2. Which statistical methods are given to find significant sample of
   my data?
3. Since I consider the measurements in the first
   meters(highest frequency of suitable area) very important in my
   distribution should I use a method not based on standard deviation?

Sorry if my question is unprecise but I have poor mathematical knowledge.

Comment: 1. could you clarify what the plot is showing? What are the variables on the axes? How are the points obtained? 2. The word significant has a particular kind of meaning in statistics that I don't think fits what you're trying to say here. i suggest avoiding jargon (instead choosing an ordinary English word or phrase) that conveys your intent; can you explain clearly what you're trying to achieve? What is it you're trying to find out from the data?

Comment: Hi Glen, thank you for answering.
I had a table with two columns, which represent two numeric continuous variable: height and areas. At each row, I have one height value and an amount of square meter (eg. at 6 height meter there are 18141 square meters). The point in the plot are the amount of square meter at that height(eg. 18141 at meter 6).
I don't want to prove any hypothesis(no inductive statistic). I just want to find a curve that has the best fit for those points.
Before modeling the curve, should I "clean" my data?

Comment: Your question is somewhat inscrutable because the graph itself includes an answer: the black curve already fits the points.  Are you looking for a formula for that curve?  Or, recognizing that it is not the only curve passing through the points, are you hoping to identify some such curve that is "best" in some sense?  What sense would that be?

Comment: Yes, I need a formula for the curve, and I have to identify which curve mayf represent the relationship between those two variables, finding a good compromise between simplification and precision.
So in the end I would like to reproduce something like this: https://davetang.org/muse/2013/05/09/on-curve-fitting/

Comment: "*the question is at which height the 95 % of the total Suitable area are located*" This is asking for a range of heights, not a single height, and it's not clear how you want to choose this range.

Comment: Ok, so a _range of heights_ in which 95%of the total Suitable areas are located. II would then exclude the heights in which the number of suitable areas is very small. Maybe there is a statistical formula that establishes the smallest group dimension in a given population to consider that group "important" in the total population. Eg. If I have 2000 measurements distributed among 5 groups. A group is overall "important" in the total population if at least 500 measurements.  belongs to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I extracted data from the scatterplot for analysis. Except for the first two data points, I see two separate models - one model for height below 16 meters and one model for height above 16 meters. Combining these two models would not require data reduction. I suspect that there might be some dominant effect above and below approximately 16 meters.

For height below 16 meters a hyperbolic type equation "y = (a + (b * x)) / (c + x)" seems to fit well, with parameters a = -3.6248957321627102E+04, b =  1.6715762703817916E+04, and c = -2.5094538863935254E+00 yielding RMSE = 149.6 and R-squared = 0.9908:

[image: below]

For height above 16 meters a Lorentzian peak type equation, " y = a/ (b + pow(x-c, d))" seems to be a possible candidate, with parameters a = 6.7383016504505267E+06, b = 4.0349701664549445E+02, c = 1.6059999999999995E+01, and d = 3.2099267050815645E+00 yielding RMSE = 374.0 and R-squared =  0.9957:

[image: above]

I did not model any overlap near 16 meters, adding one or two points of overlap between the two models would be a good idea. If you use the "two models" route, the values I have provided should be good initial parameter estimates for your own non-linear fitting with the actual data.

Comment: Hi James, thank you for your answer and the model! 
May I ask you which steps in your methodology you made in order to get the formula?  Did you use some kind of model that you feed with my data, or a script in R?

Comment: A) Visually there are two distinct shapes to the data, split at 20 meters or so. B) Split the data at 20 meters and perform equation searches for simple equations. C) Initial results show 20 meter split is not optimal by model complexity. D) Iterate equation searches with different split points to find the two simplest models that give a good fit to both sections. Note that I used my zunzun.com "function finder" for the equation searches, it has a genetic algorithm to find initial parameter estimates for fitting non-linear equations. Mostly I was just clicking browser buttons on the web site.

Comment: In the question you mention your supervisor. Did they have any comment on this model?

Comment: No. Actually I dont see my supervisor so often and I´m still changing the dataset I will fit into the model. Still it was important to see your workflow and at the first equation is still usable :).

Comment: how were you able to find out the RMSE and R squared of the fit? To replicate your steps I used R but I am struggling to find a solution.

Comment: For RMSE, Root Mean Squared Error, A) Square the regression errors. B) Find the mean (average) of those squared values. C) Take the square root of that mean. For R-squared (R2) I use "R2 = 1.0 - (regression_error_variance / dependent_data_variance)".